# Empty bin with bag that is too heavy

Tags: cleaning, plastics, trash

Yesterday I had to empty the garbage bin which contained a heavy plastic bag. The bag turned out to be too heavy and it ripped at some point. I decided I had to get some stuff out and put that in a new plastic bag, which was quite gross and took more time than I wanted to.

I was hoping there would be a more efficient way. I live on the first floor of an apartment so lifting the bin and turning it upside down in a garbage can is not an option.

I want a solution for when this problem reoccurs.

Comment: Not really a hack, but check the bag from time to time and remove it befor it is to heavy. Easy as that :)

Comment: Can you reach under the bag? If so I've got an idea.

Comment: Buy better bags? How about double bagging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding the situation you could:

- Lie the bin on its side after tying the bag and ease the bag out that way. Rolling and pulling could help.

Ways to stop this from occurring:

- Take a rubber band or just tie off the bottom of the bag so that when you fill it you will fill it only partially and then the bag will be lighter.

Comment: That could actually work!

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

- insert 2 bags, one inside the other in your bin.
- make a cradle: a net or webbing that fits around the bag. Place the cradle in the empty bin, then place the bag inside the cradle. When it's full; lift the cradle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not stingy with the bags, just put a Second bag from the top and lift your can up side down.

With this way, you used 2 bags, but together they're strong.

Comment: Garbage bags usually tear at the point where you're holding them. With your solution, you still have the entire weight of the bag concentrated on 1 bag.

Answer (score 0):

Not a hack, but buy a smaller bin - means you have to empty it more often, but at least it won't mean the contents are so heavy the bags tear. It's certainly the solution I ended up with, living in a similar situation...

Answer (score 0):

Use a wheelbarrow. Or a kid-sized dump truck. Or something else like that.

No, seriously.

Assuming your apartment building has an elevator, just use that for the wheelbarrow.